# Set view to be at bottom of camera preview?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-layout, android-camera

I'd like to set the position of the TextView to **always** be at the bottom of the camera preview.

This is not the case with my layout below. When the user changes the aspect the ratio of the camera preview (ex: from 16:9 to 4:3), the TextView remains in the same position and is no longer at the bottom of the preview.

How do I set the position of the TextView to **always** be at the bottom (left) of the camera preview?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.activities.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/root"
        android:background="@color/black"
        tools:context=".ui.activities.MainActivity">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_frame"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:paddingTop="8dp">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/preview_container"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent">

                <androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
                    android:id="@+id/preview"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,9:16"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/preview"

                    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                    android:text="Text Test" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ui.activities.MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".ui.activities.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_frame"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="8dp">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/preview_container"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">

            <androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
                android:id="@+id/preview"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,9:16"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_gravity="bottom"

            android:textColor="#ffffffff"
            android:text="Text Test" />
    </FrameLayout>
   
</RelativeLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I need the RelativeLayout, unfortunately

Comment: @Haido Check the updated anwser

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i dont have enough reputation for comment so i will try answer directly

This problem occurs because you set your textview bottom to bottom with camera preview while use ConstraintLayout. I can give you two option for solve this,

first change textview from app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf to app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf.

Second try for wrap it with linearlayout and set orientation to vertical.

Comment: This doesn't work, unfortunately. I updated the question with clearer code.